# My practice webpage is completely empty and I do not know why

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet, user-agent

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="This is a practice website">
<title>Everything Practice</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="Resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<html>
<body>

<!--Title and Banner-->

<header>
<title>
  <h1>Flip 'n' Sell</h1>
<title>

<nav>
  <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Info</li>
      <li>Help</li>
      <li>Selling</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 </header>

 </body>
 </html>`
```

Here is my html for my page so far
and here is my css. As you can see, all that I have done is styled it to where the default margin and
padding is nonexistent. What when I load this up and look at the webpage, there's nothing, nothing at all. What am I doing wrong. I still new to this all by the way.

```
* {
margin: none;
padding: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `<title>` tags or move it into the `<head>` where it belongs. Your HTML is invalid which is why it doesn't display

Comment: you can validate your html here: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Thank you I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the opening `<html>` tag to under the Doctype declaration before the `<head>` tag, and change or remove the `<title>` tag from your body.

The title tag is defining a title for the entire document (what's shown on the browser tab) and may be causing some confusion when rendering the page.[See W3 School's post on the title tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp)

Comment: I am a moron thank you. I forgot that the title is supposed to go in the head. Thank you. I took a break from coding and forgot.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="This is a practice website">
        <title>Everything Practice</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="Resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Title and Banner-->
        <header>
            <h1>Flip 'n' Sell</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Info</li>
                    <li>Help</li>
                    <li>Selling</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
     </body>
 </html>
```

The fix was your title tag was not terminated. Needed the corresponding `</title>` but in reality the title tag does not belong there and should be removed as I did in my example.